# XStream ForbiddenClassException when using a custom Forager with OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I recently upgraded optaplanner version from version 7.0.0 to version 7.4.1. I use a custom Forager declared in the config file like this:

```
...
<forager class="com.mycompany.MyCustomForagerConfig">
            <acceptedCountLimit>100</acceptedCountLimit>
</forager>
...
```

Everything worked without hassle with the previous OptaPlanner version, but after the upgrade I got a problem while OptaPlanner reads the config.xml file:

```
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException
cause-message       : com.mycompany.MyCustomForagerConfig
class               : org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig
required-type       : org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
line number         : 137
class[1]            : org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig
version             : 1.4.10
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
    …
```

It seems somewhat related to this issue https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-896 (resolved) for the latest version (7.5.0), so I tried to upgrade but the problem persists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `@XStreamAlias` on your MyCustomForagerConfig and do something like this:

```
((XStreamXmlSolverFactory) solverFactory).addXStreamAnnotations(MyCustomForagerConfig.class);
```

Out of curiosity, why do you need a custom forager? Does it add a functionality that OptaPlanner should do out of the box?

Comment: Thanks. I use a custom forager to plan all the critical entity planning before other entity. A custom factory creates the moves in the right temporal order and when the planning entity is allocated, the custom forager set a variable (used by the factory) to avoid to modify again the planning entity just allocated. It’s a way to constrain a tabu search algorithm to behave like a greedy one. Something that I think I could definitely obtain with one of the construction heuristics that now OptaPlanner provides out of the box.

Comment: Yes, throw away that very old hacky code (CH's have been around for ages) and use a Construction Heuristic (or if need be a custom phase, see example classes that end with Initializer). Even if you have multiple variables, there is now support for sequantial CH's instead of cartesian product CH's.