# Custom Acceptor in OptaPlanner

Tags: xstream, optaplanner

I would like to implement a custom acceptor in OptaPlanner, but I wasn't able to find a minimal working example anywhere. Does anybody know how to do this?

The documentation is too vague to solve my problem. I keep getting a `ForbiddenClassException` and cannot solve it even with `@XStreamAlias` (as answered here: [XStream ForbiddenClassException when using a custom Forager with OptaPlanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187174/xstream-forbiddenclassexception-when-using-a-custom-forager-with-optaplanner)). Probably this is because I know next to nothing about XStream.

The reason I want this is to try and get away from a local optima. I have two types of planning entities X and Y in a kind-of hierarchical relationship: the pair of values of an X-entity and a Y-entity can trigger conflicts, and the X-entities are used in multiple (many) pairs. Because of this, moves on X-entities cause a lot of conflicts once the values on Y-entities have been optimised.

The acceptor I have in mind would randomly enter a "craziness" state, where it will only accept moves on X-entities, and randomly go back to normal behaviour (e.g. 10x more likely to quit than to enter). This is just a random thought, I would like to experiment with this.
I would like to use this together with Tabu Search (as in, only accept moves accepted by both acceptors).

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a new metaheuristic.

The easiest way to try it out is to just fork OptaPlanner and expand `AcceptorConfig` to also build your `Acceptor`. If it's any good  - proven by benchmarks against the other acceptor types on at least 3 examples in `optaplanner-examples` of at least 5 datasets per example - and if you want to share - we'd love to add it upstream!

That being said: inventing a good metaheuristic - one that actually passes the trial of being better on one of the 25 optaplanner examples - is non-trivial. I 've tried to invent my own, several times, and always failed :) And even some metaheuristics published in academic papers, don't pass that trial (for good reason, they are consistently inferior, but it's relatively easy to circumvent that in a paper).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My issue is specific to the structure of my problem: I couldn't figure out a way to use existing metaheuristics to get out of this kind of local optima. I have a question relevant to your advice then: are there problems with this kind of structure among the examples? Also, before going through the forking, editing and benchmarking, I would like to see if it even works on my problem. I take it the easiest way is to extend `Acceptor` and `AcceptorConfig`. Would you be able to provide a minimal structure for both? Very appreciated! (And thanks for pushing OptaPlanner!)

Comment: To get out of local optima, that you can't get out with the out-of-the-box acceptors, 99% of the time the answer is a custom move, not a different acceptor. When in your local optima, figure out which kind of move would escape from it. Then build a generalized version of that custom move.

Comment: That would be a bold first move (i.e. change the "structure" of the solution) and then a cascade of moves fixing the (many) problems resulting from the first move. I went down this path in the past, but the moves ended up taking too long to compute. I also feel these moves are "too structured" and "too deterministic". Ideally I would like the solver to be forced to make a not-so-good move (e.g. with a custom acceptor, or with a dip in acceptedCountLimit) and then deal with the consequences (e.g. via tabu search). I would appreciate if you shared your thoughts on my idea.